# Where can I find the soundtrack played for the Oregairu Visual Novel for PS Vita?

Tags: music, oregairu

Where can I find the soundtrack played for the Oregairu Visual Novel for PS Vita? I really like the music in it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this soundtrack hasn't been made into an official release. This might be of help, it's incomplete though https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5h7QaSWKOUc